# Unity 3D not longer working after upgrade on a Quadro NVS 140M/

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz

After upgrading Unity 3D is not longer working. I tryed several things:

- unity --reset
- re-enabling unity plugin
- reinstall of ccsm, unity, ...

What can I do to get unity working? Unity 2D, Gnome sessions works fine.

```
    tony@xllap ~ # /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
    OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
    OpenGL renderer string: Quadro NVS 140M/PCI/SSE2
    OpenGL version string:  3.3.0 NVIDIA 285.05.09

    Not software rendered:    yes
    Not blacklisted:          yes
    GLX fbconfig:             yes
    GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
    GL npot or rect textures: yes
    GL vertex program:        yes
    GL fragment program:      yes
    GL vertex buffer object:  yes
    GL framebuffer object:    yes
    GL version is 1.4+:       yes

    Unity 3D supported:       yes

    tony@xllap:~$ unity --reset
    WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
    unity-panel-service: Kein Prozess gefunden
    Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
    Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
    Backend     : gconf
    Integration : true
    Profile     : unity
    Adding plugins
    Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
    Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
    Initializing core options...done
    Initializing bailer options...done
    Initializing detection options...done
    Initializing composite options...done
    Initializing opengl options...done
    Initializing decor options...done
    Initializing mousepoll options...done
    Initializing vpswitch options...done
    Initializing animation options...done
    Initializing snap options...done
    compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
    Initializing expo options...done
    Initializing move options...done
    Initializing place options...done
    Initializing grid options...done
    Initializing gnomecompat options...done
    Initializing wall options...done
    Initializing ezoom options...done
    Initializing workarounds options...done
    Initializing resize options...done
    Initializing fade options...done
    Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
    Initializing scale options...done
    I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/tony/.compiz/session/106db7534999063ba5131867168837080100000180430006"
    Initializing session options...done
    error in geis_init

    Screen geometry changed:
    1680x0x1920x1080
    0x0x1680x1050

    unity-panel-service: Kein Prozess gefunden
    unity-panel-service: Kein Prozess gefunden
    Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` in a terminal?

Comment: The output  of /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p is visible in the code section of my post.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/860707

Looks like if you got here by installing xorg-edgers, then (from the bug):

```
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

You may need to reboot after this, but at least restart X:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```