# Unity Doesn't run after upgrading via xorg-edgers

Tags: unity, drivers, performance

After doing the xorg-edgers upgrade, I can't log into unity but I can access gnome 3. Any reasons why. The performance boost is amazing but I don't want to go back to the old drivers.

unity 2d works. compiz crashes and the following error is left in dmesg

```
[  530.302141] compiz[3247] general protection ip:7f038283bd30 sp:7fff81df2eb8 error:0 in libutouch-geis.so.1.2.0[7f0382831000+17000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are some problems in xorg-edgers, this is the one I hit:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/860707
- [Unity 3D not longer working after upgrade on a Quadro NVS 140M/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66745/unity-3d-not-longer-working-after-upgrade-on-a-quadro-nvs-140m/74933#74933)

To get back to something more stable:

```
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

Afterwards, restart X:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Does Unity 2D work? If yes, install compiz-config:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

open it and look if the plugin unity is checked. If not, check it, restart your computer and unity 3d works.

Comment: Well that didn't work. I'll just stick with Gnome3 and screw Unity. Thanks for the help anyways.