# How do I install Nvidia drivers in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: nvidia

I love Ubuntu but 
My # 1 issue with the 173 nVidia drivers that I have installed is
the size of my desktop icons! They are way too big (everything is too big).
I would like to improve on the resolution my Display is set to by upgrading to a better driver!

read my pastie please
It is full of system info and logs (about the issue at hand)

http://pastie.org/3589050

I need help please 
I can't afford to upgrade to new hardware right now <

Answer (score 2):

Best way I have installed NVIDIA drivers is by downloading them directly from the NVIDIA website. Then from there, I use Terminal and run the following commands to install them (note filename name may differ from what you download:

`$sudo chmod a+x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.20.run`

`$sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.20.run`

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings`. Then try to launch `nvidia-settings` using the terminal and try to adjust the resolution from there.

Comment: Please re-edit your question with this info - it is very difficult to read this in comment format.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer on askubuntu.com. By adding the ppa from “xorg crack pushers” team I solved my display issues! There is one big issue though, you might lose access to Unity 3D.

I think Unity 3D does not like xorg-edgers updates. But, I use Gnome-shell and so, not being able to use Unity-3D is fine.

So, here is what I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

My old driver was removed and the current driver 295.20 was installed.

After that, when I logged into Unity 3D, all that loaded was the wallpaper.
So, I went to one of the tty's. To get to the tty's, press the following keyboard combination:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo reboot
```

I then logged back in. gnome-shell or Unity 2D or KDE all worked fine.

nVidia X server settings works like it should and I set my Display from 1024x768 to 1280x1024.

You have to purge xorg-edgers from your system to get Unity 3D to work again.

[Unity Doesn't run after upgrading via xorg-edgers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68099/unity-doesnt-run-after-upgrading-via-xorg-edgers)

I will wait for Ubuntu 12.04 to see if Unity 3D works for me again!

Comment: Unity 3D is once again working on my system I updated this morning using via-xorg-edgers! Just read the Pastie http://pastie.org/3659699  check out the  update manage history log. Maybe someone can explain what happened.